# startx error when setting up X server on archlinux

Tags: linux, xorg, arch-linux, libraries

I am trying to install X on my archlinux home desktop. I get this error when trying to start it (startx/xinit):

```
[root@computer ~]# startx
xauth: file /root/.Xauthority does not exist
xauth: file /root/.Xauthority does not exist

/usr/bin/X: /usr/lib/libz.so.1: version 'ZLIB_1.2.5.2' not found (required by /usr/lib/libfontenc.so.1)
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

I googled around and asked in #archlinux irc, but couldn't resolve the issue.

Comment: `useradd -m -g users -G audio,lp,optical,storage,video,wheel,games,power,scanner -s /bin/bash username
cp /etc/skel/.xinitrc ~/.xinitrc`
create a user and add that user to the default groups and do a startx. don't start x with root. Try if that works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:
Run `ldd /usr/bin/Xorg`

You should get a line that looks like this:

```
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0xb7357000)
```

If `ldd` claims that it can't resolve what file `libz.so.1` is in, then uninstall and reinstall `zlib`:

```
pacman -R -f zlib 
pacman -S zlib
```

If `ldd` can find a specific `libz.so.1`, then check to see if that file constitutes a broken symbolic link:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/libz.so.1
```

(Or whatever `ldd` told you that `libz.so.1` resolves to).

On my Arch boxes, `/usr/lib/libz.so.1` is a symbolic link of `libz.so.1.2.6`. If `/usr/lib/libz.so.1` links to some weird place, like a home directory, track down why - that shouldn't happen.

Ensure that whatever file that `ldd` resolves `libz.so.1` to actually exists, and has contents. I get this:

```
% file libz.so.1.2.6
libz.so.1.2.6: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0xb32fb568a025a99ed67220243b487b93ae8ef948, stripped
```

If the link exists, but the linked-to `libz.so.1.2.6` doesn't exist, perhaps you can do the two `pacman` command sequence above and get everything back.  I guess I'd advise against just doing the two `pacman` commands, until you understand what's going on.  Something must have changed, unless this is a new installation, and somehow the `zlib` package didn't get installed.

Answer (score 2):

Upon executing `startx` in the terminal, I got an identical error message. I fixed it by`pacman -Sy zlib`, which updated the zlib package. That fixed it for me. I'm very new to arch however, so this may not be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the `zlib` thing isn't the issue, this was my problem (expanded based on comment by user14039).  Also for security reasons it is much better to run X as a regular user instead of root:

**As sudo or root user, run the following (substitute username for your user name):**

```
usermod -a -G audio,lp,optical,storage,video,wheel,games,power,scanner <username>
```

**Now as non-root user:**

Copy the skeleton `.xinitrc` file to your home dir:

```
cp /etc/skel/.xinitrc ~/.xinitrc
```

Uncomment or add the startup of the window manager you want to use (I use Gnome):

```
echo "exec gnome-session" >> ~/.xinitrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
yum -y groups install "KDE Plasma Workspaces"
```

and

```
echo "exec startkde" >> ~/.xinitrc
```

finally

```
startx
```

Comment: How does an `echo` command help?  Did you mean to say `>> ~/.xinitrc`?